# Android Development- onclicklistener setting wrong image

Tags: android, onclicklistener

```
package com.example.sliderapp;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // add functionality for android button
        MyClickListener listener = new MyClickListener();
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(listener);

        // add functionality for apple button
        MyClickListener2 listener2 = new MyClickListener2();
        Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button2.setOnClickListener(listener2);

        // Add functionality for don't care button
        MyClickListener3 listener3 = new MyClickListener3();
        Button button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        button3.setOnClickListener(listener3);

        //Add functionality for reset button
        MyClickListener4 listener4 = new MyClickListener4();
        Button button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        button4.setOnClickListener(listener4);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * click listener method referring to android button
     * 
     * @author Ross
     * 
     */
    private class MyClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {

        public void onClick(View view) {

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.happypng);
        }

    }

    /**
     * click listener method referring to apple button
     * 
     * @author Ross
     * 
     */
    private class MyClickListener2 implements View.OnClickListener {

        public void onClick(View view) {

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.happypng);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Click listener referring to don't care button
     * @author Ross
     *
     */
    private class MyClickListener3 implements View.OnClickListener {

        public void onClick(View view) {

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.whynotpng);

            ImageView imageView2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

            imageView2.setImageResource(R.drawable.whynotpng);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Click listener referring to Reset button
     * @author Ross
     *
     */
    private class MyClickListener4 implements View.OnClickListener {

        public void onClick(View view) {

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

            ImageView imageView2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

            imageView2.setImageResource(R.drawable.apple_gray_logo);
        }

    }



}
```

In the code above the last method (myClicklistener4) I am trying to set up the imageResources as stated however it is setting them equal to .whynotpng like in the 3rd class. I am unsure why this is happening.

Comment: Do the other onClick's work? Also your code can be shortened dramatically.

Comment: Yes the first two on clicks work as intended but the last 2 do not, how could i shorten my code? thanks

Comment: for shortening code ..apply only 1 onClickListner applying this as arg and follow the eclipse instruction and use switch case for individual work in onClick().

Comment: u have applied on imageview1/2 in bottom 2 as well, u want them only..?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot tell you where exacltly your error occurs as I can't see anything particular wrong in your code. This is your code shortened. Does it work now? And do you have saved all your drawables in the right folder and with the right names?

```
package com.example.sliderapp;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private ImageView ivFirst, ivSecond;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // register your button listeners
        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.button1)).setOnClickListener(this);
        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.button2)).setOnClickListener(this);
        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.button3)).setOnClickListener(this);
        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.button4)).setOnClickListener(this);
        // you can also define the onClick method via xml by calling   android:onClick="onClick"

        // save your ImageViews so that you don't have to find them for every buttonclick
        ivFirst = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        ivSecond = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // depending on which button is clicked do some action
        switch(view.getId()) {
            case R.id.button1:
                ivFirst.setImageResource(R.drawable.happypng);
                break;
            case R.id.button2:
                ivFirst.setImageResource(R.drawable.happypng);
                break;
            case R.id.button3:
                ivFirst.setImageResource(R.drawable.whynotpng);
                ivSecond.setImageResource(R.drawable.whynotpng);
                break;
            case R.id.button4:
                ivFirst.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                ivSecond.setImageResource(R.drawable.apple_gray_logo);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the approach to short down your code, is already explained by "**Endzeit**" .

Another approach which you can follow to short down your code is explained below:

First:

```
Add  android:onClick="method name" in all 4 Buttons in your xml file.
```

Example:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="myClick"
        android:text="button1" />
```

Similarly do it for button2, button3 and button 4

Now, add this code in your Java class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private ImageView imageView1, imageView2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    imageView2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void myClick(View view) {
    // depending on which button is clicked do some action
    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:
            imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.happypng);
            break;
        case R.id.button2:
            imageView2.setImageResource(R.drawable.happypng);
            break;
        case R.id.button3:
            imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.whynotpng);
            imageView2.setImageResource(R.drawable.whynotpng);
            break;
        case R.id.button4:
            imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            imageView2.setImageResource(R.drawable.apple_gray_logo);
            break;
    }
  }
}
```

Note: You dont have to find the ids of buttons in this case.